# Таймер обратного обратного отсчета

Tags: jquery

Здраствуйте! Подскажите! как чтобы таймер после окончания отсчета возобновлялся и после каждой перезагрузки не перезагружался заново, а продолжал бы свой отсчет.

```
    <div id="countdown_dashboard">
```

**хтмл разметка:**

```
    <div class="dash days_dash">
                <span class="dash_title">дней</span>
                <div class="digit">0</div>
                <div class="digit">0</div>
            </div>

            <div class="dash hours_dash">
                <span class="dash_title">часов</span>
                <div class="digit">0</div>
                <div class="digit">0</div>
            </div>

            <div class="dash minutes_dash">
                <span class="dash_title">минут</span>
                <div class="digit">0</div>
                <div class="digit">0</div>
            </div>

            <div class="dash seconds_dash">
                <span class="dash_title">секунд</span>
                <div class="digit">0</div>
                <div class="digit">0</div>
            </div>

        </div>

введите код здесь(function($){

$.fn.countDown = function (options) {

    config = {};

    $.extend(config, options);

    diffSecs = this.setCountDown(config);

    if (config.onComplete)
    {
        $.data($(this)[0], 'callback', config.onComplete);
    }
    if (config.omitWeeks)
    {
        $.data($(this)[0], 'omitWeeks', config.omitWeeks);
    }

    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' .digit').html('<div class="top"></div><div class="bottom"></div>');
    $(this).doCountDown($(this).attr('id'), diffSecs, 500);

    return this;

};

$.fn.stopCountDown = function () {
    clearTimeout($.data(this[0], 'timer'));
};

$.fn.startCountDown = function () {
    this.doCountDown($(this).attr('id'),$.data(this[0], 'diffSecs'), 500);
};

$.fn.setCountDown = function (options) {
    var targetTime = new Date();

    if (options.targetDate)
    {
        targetTime = new Date(options.targetDate.month + '/' + options.targetDate.day + '/' + options.targetDate.year + ' ' + options.targetDate.hour + ':' + options.targetDate.min + ':' + options.targetDate.sec + (options.targetDate.utc ? ' UTC' : ''));
    }
    else if (options.targetOffset)
    {
        targetTime.setFullYear(options.targetOffset.year + targetTime.getFullYear());
        targetTime.setMonth(options.targetOffset.month + targetTime.getMonth());
        targetTime.setDate(options.targetOffset.day + targetTime.getDate());
        targetTime.setHours(options.targetOffset.hour + targetTime.getHours());
        targetTime.setMinutes(options.targetOffset.min + targetTime.getMinutes());
        targetTime.setSeconds(options.targetOffset.sec + targetTime.getSeconds());
    }

    var nowTime = new Date();

    diffSecs = Math.floor((targetTime.valueOf()-nowTime.valueOf())/1000);

    $.data(this[0], 'diffSecs', diffSecs);

    return diffSecs;
};

$.fn.doCountDown = function (id, diffSecs, duration) {
    $this = $('#' + id);
    if (diffSecs <= 0)
    {
        diffSecs = 0;
        if ($.data($this[0], 'timer'))
        {
            clearTimeout($.data($this[0], 'timer'));
        }
    }

    secs = diffSecs % 60;
    mins = Math.floor(diffSecs/60)%60;
    hours = Math.floor(diffSecs/60/60)%24;
    if ($.data($this[0], 'omitWeeks') == true)
    {
        days = Math.floor(diffSecs/60/60/24);
        weeks = Math.floor(diffSecs/60/60/24/7);
    }
    else 
    {
        days = Math.floor(diffSecs/60/60/24)%7;
        weeks = Math.floor(diffSecs/60/60/24/7);
    }

    $this.dashChangeTo(id, 'seconds_dash', secs, duration ? duration : 800);
    $this.dashChangeTo(id, 'minutes_dash', mins, duration ? duration : 1200);
    $this.dashChangeTo(id, 'hours_dash', hours, duration ? duration : 1200);
    $this.dashChangeTo(id, 'days_dash', days, duration ? duration : 1200);
    $this.dashChangeTo(id, 'weeks_dash', weeks, duration ? duration : 1200);

    $.data($this[0], 'diffSecs', diffSecs);
    if (diffSecs > 0)
    {
        e = $this;
        t = setTimeout(function() { e.doCountDown(id, diffSecs-1) } , 1000);
        $.data(e[0], 'timer', t);
    } 
    else if (cb = $.data($this[0], 'callback')) 
    {
        $.data($this[0], 'callback')();
    }

};

$.fn.dashChangeTo = function(id, dash, n, duration) {
      $this = $('#' + id);

      for (var i=($this.find('.' + dash + ' .digit').length-1); i>=0; i--)
      {
            var d = n%10;
            n = (n - d) / 10;
            $this.digitChangeTo('#' + $this.attr('id') + ' .' + dash + ' .digit:eq('+i+')', d, duration);
      }
};

$.fn.digitChangeTo = function (digit, n, duration) {
    if (!duration)
    {
        duration = 800;
    }
    if ($(digit + ' div.top').html() != n + '')
    {

        $(digit + ' div.top').css({'display': 'none'});
        $(digit + ' div.top').html((n ? n : '0')).slideDown(duration);

        $(digit + ' div.bottom').animate({'height': ''}, duration, function() {
            $(digit + ' div.bottom').html($(digit + ' div.top').html());
            $(digit + ' div.bottom').css({'display': 'block', 'height': ''});
            $(digit + ' div.top').hide().slideUp(10);

        });
    }
};

 })(jQuery);

<script type="text/javascript">

    // Устанавливаем счетчик
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $('#countdown_dashboard').countDown({
            targetOffset: {
                'day':      0,
                'month':    0,
                'year':     0,
                'hour':     2,
                'min':      0,
                'sec':      0
            },
            omitWeeks: true // Отключаем вывод количества недель
        });
    });
    // Запускаем счет
    function start() {
        $('#countdown_dashboard').startCountDown();
    };

        </script>
```

Comment: данные лучше как-то сохранять, например в куках ) и при перезагрузке, считывать эти данные )

Comment: Какие куки? Используйте Web Storage!

Comment: WebStorage чтобы сохранить одну цифру? Букву? Символ? Еще и разрешение у клиента на это спрашивать!

Comment: А что вам не нравится? Для этого нужно подгрузить 500кб или 2мб что-ли? Можно и куки, но это уже старая технология и надо приучать себя пользоваться web storage, поддержка которого достаточно широкая. http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage

Comment: Я за использование новых технологий. Мне очень нравится Web Storage. Но в данном случае более уместно использовать куки.